# How to restrict local address books used for recipient lookup

Tags: thunderbird

Using Thunderbird v102 on Ubuntu 20.04 (Elementary OS).

I have synced my address book with Exchange and I have now over 18k contacts. I like the fact that virtually anybody will be in it, however it is very slow when composing emails (a few seconds of freeze when typing an email).

Now 90+% of my emails are sent to people not in this 18k list. So I'd like the contact lookup to be done only on a specific address book that has about 2k entries. This was the one used before I synced the other 16k in, and lookup was fast enough.

In the options I have the opportunity to select "local address books" (e.g. ALL of them), or not (e.g. NONE of them).

This is too extreme, is it possible to select a single subset?

Bonus question: how is this so slow? I don't see how a SQLite database would be that slow for text search among 18k, though I don't know what technology Mozilla uses (`file` tells me "Mozilla Mork database", whatever that is — the Wikipedia page does not have a lot of praise for it).

Edit: I got curious, I found out that Mork was dropped a few years ago and that now it's in SQLite. I found a 22MB address book file which looks like the one, and searching with `select * from properties where name='PrimaryEmail' and value like '%whatever%'` yields a result in 78ms (with `sqlite3` CLI).
I wouldn't mind getting this into RAM at all times (and by the way the Linux filesystem cache probably does it anyway) to get fast results all the time.
I have no idea why it's so slow.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Giacomo1968 — however, despite my out of topic question being of interest, I'd rather have my post focused on the actual issue: restrict address books looked up. The rest is more like a rhetorical rant.

Comment: No problem! I see you undid it and that’s fine.